# how to optimize a command?

Tags: linux, command

I am working with linux, I am looking for to optimize this command, 
I would appreciated any help.
I want first replace the | to / of a file1.txt then replace the " " of the same file to nothing and then to get the first five chars of that file and count the result.

```
sed 's#|#/#g' file1.txt | sed 's# ##g' | rev | cut -c 1-5 | rev | wc -c
```

I am also interested in other forms to get the same result.

Comment: please edit your Q to show a small sample input and expected output. Good luck.

Comment: I added an a small description of the result that I am expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following command may help you.

```
sed -e 's/|/\//g' -e 's/ //g' file1.txt |rev|head -1|cut -c1-5|rev|wc -m
```

Explaination:

sed would replace matching pattern with required pattern.

-e allow to make multiple statement in same sed command.

rev would reverse all the character line by line

head -1 would print first five characters of that file. However if you want first five characters of each line then eliminate head command.

cut with -c parameter would print required range of characters(in your case first five characters)

wc -m would give character count